# lablgtk can't find gtk+ 2.0 on Mac

Tags: macos, gtk, opam, lablgtk

I want to install `lablgtk` on my mac to use some software who needs it. I try to install it with `opam install lablgtk` but at the `make world` I got this error :

```
=> This package requires gtk+ 2.0 development packages installed on your system
=> To solve pkg-config issues, you may need to do
   'export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig' and retry
```

I tried using `opam depext -i lablgtk` but it finds Gtk

```
Warning: gtk+ 2.24.32_2 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 2.24.32_2, run `brew reinstall gtk+`
```

I did the export and tried `eval 'opam config env'` but I got the same error again and again. I installed Gtk+ and used a lot of pkg export that I found in internet but I can't resolve this problem. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

For my case, it was that somehow pkg-config was broke so that it didn't have a link to libffi.pc which is required when the ./configure file building lablgtx package uses pkg-config to locate the installed gtx.h. 
Hence, it was fixed for my case by

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"`